# Entity Framework - how to save entity without saving related objects

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my Entity Framework, I have three related entities '**Client**', '**ClientAddress**' and '**LookupAddressType**'. "**LookupAddressType**" is a master class specifying the type of available address type, like business address, residential address etc. **ClientAddress** depend on **LookupAddresstype** and **Client**. While **saving** a **Client** entity with relevant ClientAddress data, i'm getting following error.

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_LookupAddressType'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LookupAddressType'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

I do not need LookupAddressType to be inserted. Here I just need the relevant lookupAddressTypeId to be inserted in clientAddress entity.

The Saving code is like this:

```
Add(Client);
_objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

how can i do this?

The Load Code is below:

```
private void LoadClientDetails(EFEntities.Client _Client)
    {

        EFEntities.LookupClientStatu clientStatus;
        var clientAddressList = new List<ClientAddress>();

        if (_Client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Assign data to client object
        _Client.ClientName = rtxtName.Text;
        _Client.Alias = rtxtAlias.Text;
        _Client.ClientCode =Int32.Parse(rtxtClientCode.Text); 
        _Client.TaxPayerID = rtxtTaxPayerId.Text;

        if (rcboStatus.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            clientStatus = new EFEntities.LookupClientStatu
                               {
                                   ClientStatusID = (Guid) (rcboStatus.SelectedValue),
                                   ClientStatusDescription = rcboStatus.Text
                               };
            _Client.LookupClientStatu = clientStatus;
        }


        //_Client.Modified = EnvironmentClass.ModifiedUserInstance.Id;

        _Client.EffectiveDate = rdtEffectiveDate.Value;

        if (rdtExpDate.Value != rdtExpDate.MinDate)
        {
            _Client.ExpirationDate = rdtExpDate.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            _Client.ExpirationDate = null;
        }

        _Client.StartDate = DateTime.Now;


        EFEntities.ClientAddress clientAddress = null;
        // Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<ClientAddress> clientAddress = new HashedSet<ClientAddress>();
        foreach (var cAddress in _clientController.client.ClientAddresses)
        {
            clientAddress = cAddress;
            break;
        }

        if (clientAddress == null)
        {
            clientAddress = new EFEntities.ClientAddress();
        }

        clientAddress.Address1 = rtxtClientAdd1.Text;
        clientAddress.Address2 = rtxtClientAdd2.Text;
        clientAddress.Address3 = rtxtClientAdd3.Text;

        // Address type details
        if (rcboClientAddType.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            clientAddress.LookupAddressType = new EFEntities.LookupAddressType
                                            {
                                                AddressTypeID = (Guid) (rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue),
                                                AddressTypeDescription = rcboClientAddType.Text
                                            };

            //clientAddress.AddressType.Id = Convert.ToByte(rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue);
        }


        clientAddress.City = rtxtClientCity.Text;
        clientAddress.Client = _Client;
```

\

```
        _Client.ClientAddresses.Add(clientAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that creates your new client.

Comment: Where do the related objects come from? If they came from the database EF should not want to save them. If you add them on the client side but you know the key you can try Attaching (.Attach) them to let the EF know that the entity with the given key is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did this to the following lines of code to make it work.

```
if (rcboClientAddType.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        clientAddress.LookupAddressType = new EFEntities.LookupAddressType
                                        {
                                            AddressTypeID = (Guid) (rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue),
                                            AddressTypeDescription = rcboClientAddType.Text
                                        };

        //clientAddress.AddressType.Id = Convert.ToByte(rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue);
    }
```

I changed the above code into this

```
if (rcboClientAddType.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //clientAddress.LookupAddressType = new EFEntities.LookupAddressType
            //                                {
            //                                    AddressTypeID = (Guid) (rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue),
            //                                    AddressTypeDescription = rcboClientAddType.Text
            //                                };
            clientAddress.AddressTypeID = (Guid)(rcboClientAddType.SelectedValue);

        }
```